# Running android application in background?

Tags: android

I having problem in my application.. I am pressing back button in my third activity but its running in running in background(i noticed by used Log statement). If again load application its starts from first activity instead of third activity. please suggest some idea to do this..
This is my back button coding

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

{

```
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
{
   moveTaskToBack(true);

}
  return true;
 }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This is intended behavior. If you don't want it to run in the background, why are you using movetasktoback? You should read up on the lifecycle of android activities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The back button pauses your current activity and pop it from the activity stack, so the previous activity will be shown. You don't have and in most cases you just shouldn't override this behaviour.

Basicly, if you're in your third activity and you press the home button, then relaunch the application the third activtiy will be shown.

Please, refer to [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. But for me When i am in third activity and i press home button and then relaunching gives me first activity. Can you give a nudge where i would have gone wrong.

Comment: could you please remove the code you posted in your question? I think it causes all your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in your third activity and then press home button. The next time if you want your activity to start from the third activity, Long press the home button and then invoke the application from this list rather than launching it from launcher activity.